# 73 Lines of Mayhem - Parse, Sort and Save to CSV in PHP CLI

Tags: php, csv, parsing

Inside of a folder named `txt` I have 138 text files (totaling 349MB) full of email addresses. I have no idea (yet) how many addresses there are. They are separated from one another by line breaks. I created the following script to read all of these files into an array, dismiss the duplicates, then sort alphabetically and save in groups of 10K per csv file. It works correctly, but it has also been running for over 8 hours (dual core i3 w/ 4 gigabizzles of ram, sata 7200 hdd) which seems excessive to me. `Top` also tells me that my program's CPU usage is 100% and it's been like that the whole while it's been running. Give my script a looksie and advise me on where I've gone so terribly wrong.

```
function writeFile($fileName, $fileData)
{

    $writeFileOpen = fopen('csv/' . $fileName, 'w');
    fwrite($writeFileOpen, $fileData) or die('Unable to write file: ' . $fileName);
    fclose($writeFileOpen);

}

function openFiles()
{

    $addressList = array();
    $preventRepeat = array();

    if ($handle = opendir('txt')) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                $newList = explode("\n", trim(file_get_contents('txt/' . $file)));
                foreach ($newList as $key => $val) {
                    $val = str_replace(array(',', '"'), '', $val);
                    if (in_array($val, $preventRepeat) || !strpos($val, '@') || !$val) {
                        unset($newList[$key]);
                    }
                    $preventRepeat[] = $val;
                }
                if (empty($addressList)) {
                    $addressList = $newList;
                } else {
                    $addressList = array_merge($addressList, $newList);
                }
                unset($newList);
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    } else {
        echo 'Unable to Read Directory';
    }

    $lineNum = 1;
    $fileNum = 1;
    $fileData = '"Email Address"' . "\n";

    sort($addressList);

    $lastKey = count($addressList) - 1;

    foreach ($addressList as $key => $val) {

        if ($lineNum > 10000) {

            writeFile('emailList-' . $fileNum . '.csv', trim($fileData));

            $lineNum = 1;
            $fileNum++;
            $fileData = '"Email Address"' . "\n";

        } elseif ($key == $lastKey) {

            writeFile('emailList-' . $fileNum . '.csv', trim($fileData));

            echo 'Complete';            

        }

        $fileData .= '"' . trim($val) . '"' . "\n";
        $lineNum++;

    }

}

openFiles();
```

PS. I wrote this script in haste to accomplish a task. I can understand if you wouldn't consider this script *distribution* worthy.

EDIT: So I arrived at work today to find my script at some point exceeded 536MB of memory and quit on fatal error. I had already increased my ini file's `memory_limit` parameter from 128MB to 512MB. This doesn't necessarily reflect an issue with the script itself. I just wanted to share my frustration with the task.

Comment: You can probably make the script already twice as fast by utilizing both cores. Separate the processing across two processes, or use two threads. I find it strange that it indicates CPU usage of 100% at the moment. Shouldn't it just run on one core?

Comment: PHP doesn't support multi-threading that I'm aware of. By 100% CPU usage, I'm guessing that it's taking up a whole core - not both. I'm able to run other processes without excessive clocking.

Comment: Regarding to your edit: Don't you store all addresses twice? One in `$addressList` and once in `$preventRepeat`? Assuming all addresses are unique this would already take up 349MB * 2 of memory.

Comment: How about a quick GNU sort: `time LC_ALL=C sort -u txt/* > email.sorted`. Bonus features: still fast if the files don't fit in ram (with in-memory compression and tempfiles), and multicore since 8.6.

Comment: I just transitioned from Windows to Linux six (or so) months ago and am still getting acquainted with the ever-expansive bash and gnu tool set - will definitely check out sort's man page. What purpose does time serve in your example?

Comment: `time` measures how long the rest of the command takes, and `LC_ALL=C` ignores your locale's sort order. Neither is necessary, but they make for a quick benchmark.

Comment: That's definitely a simpler solution than what I originally came up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've written PHP, but I think I can give you a few pointers anyhow.

I believe the following line is problematic speed-wise:

```
if (in_array($val, $preventRepeat) || !strpos($val, '@') || !$val) {
...
```

The `in_array` function does a sequential case sensitive lookup across all currently stored addresses. This call will become slower and slower the more addresses you store.

The solution is to use [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) like lookup. I'm not entirely sure but I believe the PHP equivalent can be achieved by using the keys of the array instead of the values.

```
// Store a certain address.
$addressList[$val] = true;
```

Checking whether a value is present for a given key indicates whether it has already been stored. Notice how `$preventRepeat` can be removed and everything is stored in `$addressList`. This removes the need of the `array_merge`, again resulting in more performance.

Beware, this is speculation, so I'm hoping someone who is certain can verify this. :)

Relating to my earlier comment:

> You can probably make the script
>   already twice as fast by utilizing
>   both cores. Separate the processing
>   across two processes, or use two
>   threads. I find it strange that it
>   indicates CPU usage of 100% at the
>   moment. Shouldn't it just run on one
>   core?

[PHP doesn't seem to support multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209774/does-php-have-threading/209799#209799), so the only option would be to logically split the script to separate work into two different executions. If my previous comments don't improve the speed much, it's probably advisable to use a different language than PHP for these purposes.

Comment: Because I'm using PHP's `explode()` function to generate my arrays, I have no way to know or guarantee what position or key each specific value will take. Great point on having double sets of the same data, though. I removed my `$addressList` array and instead am storing those values in a temporary text file. I've also made sure to unset `$preventRepeat` before importing and array-ifying my temp file. I think my ultimate issue is that I'm trying to process way too much data at once (I'm guessing close to a billion addresses). I want them all in alphabetical order, though!

Comment: PHP allows to use strings as keys in its [associative arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). What I intented with my answer is to store the addresses -so, `$val` in your code- as keys. Keys are unique, so you don't even have to check whether the key is already present, just set the value of the key to `true` or some other relevant value. Worry about sorting later. If I were you though, I would really prefer not processing a billion addresses in PHP.

Comment: Ahh... so I should `if ($preventRepeat[$val]) { unset($newList[$key]); }` and then `$preventRepeat[$val] = TRUE;` instead of `in_array($val, $preventRepeat)` and `$preventRepeat[] = $val;`? That's brilliant!

Comment: I believe `unset` isn't even required. I would just use one list of which you set the keys, and skip the merging. Be sure to try this out on just one small file before executing it on all of the entries. ;p

Comment: I'm picking up what you're putting down. Store all values in array as keys (which doubles as duplicate prevention), forget about making a temp file, and later reverse the keys out into array values for processing.

Comment: Or use a sort on key. [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) apparently.

Comment: Thanks to your advice, my script works beautifully now. By comparison - extremely fast. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

This will be much more efficient:

```
$result = array();

if (($handle = opendir('./txt/')) !== false)
{
    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('memory_limit', -1);

    while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false)
    {
        if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..'))
        {
            if (is_resource($file = fopen('./txt/' . $file, 'rb')) === true)
            {
                while (($email = fgets($file)) !== false)
                {
                    $email = trim(str_replace(array(',', '"'), '', $email));

                    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false)
                    {
                        $result[strtolower($email)] = true;
                    }
                }

                fclose($file);
            }
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);

    if (empty($result) !== true)
    {
        ksort($result);

        foreach (array_chunk($result, 10000, true) as $key => $value)
        {
            file_put_contents('./emailList-' . ($key + 1) . '.csv', implode("\n", array_keys($value)), LOCK_EX);
        }
    }

    echo 'Done!';
}
```

Comment: +1 for using `filter_var()` (never occurred to me) - but why the identical comparison operator? Not-equal operators test against `bool` just fine without the extra overhead of type matching.

Comment: @65Fbef05: Force of habit, ignore it. @Steven Jeuris: Thank you! =)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use the command line `sort` tool, and look in to `sed` and `grep` as well. You will find that it is generally easier to use fast, well-tested, pre-built Unix tools to perform any large text operations than to write a higher-level program to do the same.

If you are just getting in to Unix, also check out:

- the [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) set of utilities which provide fantastic image processing
- the `file` tool (based on `libmagic`) which provides proper file type checking for uploaded files accepted from the public

Also, just in case those emails are going to be used to distribute unsolicited information... don't spam people: it's bad karma.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. I'm working my way through a LPIC-1 study guide in an attempt to quickly get a thorough overview (oxymoron, right?) of Linux features. Also, worry not about your e-mail inbox - I don't want to spam people. I won't go into detail, but I was using the addresses to "test" an account feature on a music/social networking site. This feature turned out to not be completely developed or broken. :)